# Многопоточный калькулятор на Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Задача сделать так, чтобы программа работала в двух потоках. Нужно искусственно усыплять поток, дабы эмулировать долгие вычисления.

В первом потоке:

1. Формируется запрос на вычисление и происходит добавление его в очередь потока `2` (при нажатии на кнопку "=" ).
2. Вывод результатов (например в qDebug), полученных из потока `2`

Во втором (доступ к потоку `2` должен быть потокобезопасным):

1. Как завершится пред. вычисление, приступать к следующему, поступившему из потока `1`.
2. Извлеченный элемент отправляется на обработку.
3. Ожидание окончания вычислений
4. Передача результата в основной поток

С классом `QThread` не знаком, + читал о нескольких способах реализации, так и не понял как сделать грамотнее.

```
void MainWindow::equal_pressed()
{
    double displayNumber;
    double secondNum = ui->display->text().toDouble();
    QString DisplayText;

    if (ui->pushButton_add->isChecked())
    {
        qDebug() << "New request: " << firstNum << " + " << secondNum;

        std::thread thread_2([&displayNumber,secondNum,this(){
            displayNumber = compute(add,firstNum,secondNum); 
        });
        thread_2.join();                                        
        // это конечно неправильно, выходит тоже самое что и в одном потоке. Где-то нужно создать std::queue мб и туда помещать запросы

        DisplayText = QString::number(displayNumber,'g',15); // только как.
        ui->display->setText(DisplayText);
        ui->pushButton_add->setChecked(false);
        qDebug() << "Result: " << displayNumber;
    }
    else if (ui->pushButton_subtract->isChecked())
    {
        qDebug() << "New request: " << firstNum << " - " << secondNum;

        displayNumber = compute(substract,firstNum,secondNum);

        DisplayText = QString::number(displayNumber,'g',15);
        ui->display->setText(DisplayText);
        ui->pushButton_subtract->setChecked(false);

        qDebug() << "Result: " << displayNumber;
    }
    else if (ui->pushButton_mult->isChecked())
    {
        qDebug() << "New request: " << firstNum << " * " << secondNum;

        displayNumber = compute(mult,firstNum,secondNum);;
        DisplayText = QString::number(displayNumber,'g',15);
        ui->display->setText(DisplayText);
        ui->pushButton_mult->setChecked(false);

        qDebug() << "Result: " << displayNumber;
    }
    else if (ui->pushButton_divide->isChecked())
    {
        qDebug() << "New request: " << firstNum << " / " << secondNum;
        try
        {
            displayNumber = compute(divide,firstNum,secondNum);;
            if (secondNum == 0.0) {
                throw 1; 
            }

            DisplayText = QString::number(displayNumber,'g',15);
            ui->display->setText(DisplayText);
            ui->pushButton_divide->setChecked(false);

            qDebug() << "Result: " << displayNumber;
        }
        catch (int e)
        {
            qDebug() << "Error: You cannot divide by zero!";
        }

        ui->pushButton_divide->setChecked(false); //чтобы можно было продолжить пользоваться программой, после деления на 0
    }

    userTypingSecondDigit = false;
}

double MainWindow::compute(int Type, double OperandA, double OperandB)
{
    switch (Type) {
        case add:
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay_ms));
            return OperandA + OperandB;
        }
        case substract:
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay_ms));
            return OperandA - OperandB;
        }
        case mult:
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay_ms));
            return OperandA * OperandB;
        }
        case divide:
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay_ms));
            return OperandA / OperandB;
        }
    }
}
```

Просьба помочь разобраться с данной задачей. QT для меня в новинку

Comment: "QT в новинку" - а) почитайте про QT.  Касательно QThread - открыли справку - почитали, посмотрели примеры. б) делайте на том, что знаете: [std::thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/) или [Winapi](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread)

Answer (score 0):

На текущий момент есть удобное API для работы с потоками, именуемое QFuture.

Для запуска задачи в новом потоке используется [QtConcurrent::run()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#run). Эта функция возвращает экземпляр класса QFuture, с которым легко провести ожидание результата и тд.

Так же, есть готовый [класс](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html) для синхронизации потоков, который позволяет дождаться результата выполнения нескольких операций без сигналов и слотов.

Comment: А можно примеры?

Comment: @bard пример псевдокода с передачей указателя на функцию
https://pastebin.com/ZHTkRshJ